# Error with layer.pendingAllAttributesList

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-2

While coding to obtain individual layers' attributes (field) list, I am stymied by the code.

I can identify a specific layer:
`MyLayer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName("TestPoint")`
which returns on "print MyLayer":
`qgis._core.QgsVectorLayer object at 0x000000000FCC6730` 
from which I infer I am correctly using MyLayer as a Layer object/pointer (or whatnot...)

However, when I run this:

`fields = Mylayer.pendingAllAttributesList()`

I force this error:

`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'pendingAllAttributesList'`

Following this statement, eventually I would run a "For field in fields...:" indent block, to iterate through the fields, but I can't even get past my error.

I get same/similar errors for other attribute functions within the API, using versions provided in code samples, and best I can tell I am duplicating relevant python code within the samples found.  Somehow, I am missing something important about the way the Attributes work, or the coding, or the list or object.

I am using the recently downloaded QGIS 2.6.0 package for windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mapLayersByName` returns a `list-of-QgsMapLayers` so you need to use `[0`] at the end to just get the single one.

The defintion for that function is:

`QList<QgsMapLayer*> QgsMapLayerRegistry::mapLayersByName(QString layerName)`

Which you can see returns a QList of QgsMapLayer, which is just a list of QgsMapLayers in Pythion.

Use `QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName("layer")[0]` to get a single layer.

Use something like this to hide the logic:

```
def layers_by_name(name, single=False):
    layers = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName("layer")
    if single:
       return layers[0]
    else:
       return layers

layer = layers_by_name("mylayer", single=True)
```

Comment: thanks, @Nathan.  The API says that -that- function returns a pointer to a layer, not returns a list.   Is this a Python thing I missed?  Is there alternate code to get the attribute/field columns, or is my stepping the correct path?  MapLayerByName returns a one-element list, of one pointer? (How would I have known -that-! ??)  Sometimes I see "instance()" in samples, and not quite sure why that sneaks in, either.

Comment: Ah, @Nathan.    So this function returns a list by definition -- the clue is the "QList<QgsMapLayer*>.   I needed that translation for the fronting portion of that definition line.  Thanks.

Comment: But....@Nathan...if the mapLayersByName(Qstring) returns a list with a single item (a single pointer) in that QList, to the layer whose name is "Qstring", why does the python statement contain (or need to contain) the "instance()" -- what is "instance()" doing for the statement?

Comment: `QgsMapLayerRegistry` is a singleton (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) i.e there is only one map layer registry, ever, so you access it though instance(). That has nothing to do with what you are getting out of it as a result.  instance() returns the instance of QgsMapLayerRegistry.  It's a gross pattern but we are stuck with that for now.

Comment: Another "Ahah", @Nathan.   Other than hearing that, from you, where would I have learned that in the API  http://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayerRegistry.html.  I appreciate your yielding clues so I can answer my own questions, later.

Comment: Ok...another usage question, if I may @Nathan: The code, to this point in our discussion, returns a set in "fields", of what appear to be field index #s , ie the set: [0,1].   Somewhere, obviously, there is a way to obtain the 'name'/heading that goes with each of the fields.  Where would I have looked in the API to unwind that bit of knowledge?   Or, better, how would that search have initiated and progressed? (as I am flogging all over looking for some derivative of Layer or Attribute, somewhere, that returns a fieldName from an Index # for the attribute/field

Answer (score 0):

This, for future readers.   I noted this clue that would be helpful

`layerSS = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName("TestPoint")
print layerSS`

returns:

`[< qgis._core.QgsVectorLayer object at 0x000000000FCC6730 >]`

while:

`layerSS = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName("TestPoint")[0]
print layerSS`

returns:
`< qgis._core.QgsVectorLayer object at 0x000000000FCC6730>`

Note the square brackets ("[ ... ]", in the first case, indicating that the result was a List with one pointer pointer as an element (a pointer with the "< ... >"), and that my error spoke of lists.

Note the absence of the brackets, in the second case, indicating that the result was a pointer

With that portion of my error identified, my next question should/would have been, how do I get the first/only element of a list.   The answer was @Nathans first clue: using the [0].